# substituting an URL only if a file was found using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

> *here's how I do :*

1. the user types a URL
2. the mod_rewrite handles URLs of the form : `^([^/\.]+)/?$` (the first
   segment in the path)
3. and redirect them to the index page : `struct.php?page=$1`
4. in the index page (struct.php) I request the content of the page
   ($_GET['page']) if it exists :

   `$content = @file_get_contents("pages/$_GET[page]/.content")`
5. if the content doesn't exist, I just request the content of the page
   `'not_found/.content'`

This is working but I'd like to keep things simple in the script and use the power of mod_rewrite to request only the pages that exist.

> *here's how I'd like to do :*

1. the user types a URL
2. the mod_rewrite handles URLs of the form : `^([^/\.]+)/?$` (the first
   segment in the path)
3. and redirect them to the index page **only if the `.content` file has been found**  : `struct.php?page=$1`

> here's my try:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine on
>
>   RewriteCond pages/$1/.content -f
>   RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ struct.php?page=$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

**note** : I'm using an `.htaccess` file

Comment: Has anyone explored using <Directory> Directive?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/\.]+)/?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/.content -f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/? struct.php?page=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Comment: genius ! never thought about using the apache env. variable to make the job. anyway `QUERY_STRING` ? you mean `REQUEST_URI`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/\.]+)/?
RewriteCond /absolute/path/pages/$1/.content -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ struct.php?page=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if it works, but you should give it a try.

Remember changing /absolute/path/ to the absolute path of the pages folder.